# Polidea/ios-class-guard - How to exclude external classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, obfuscation

I am using Polidea iOS class guard library for obfuscation. but i need to exclude all pods libraries like Infragistics, UISS, StompKit, else...

I am trying like this `CLASS_GUARD_OPTS="-F '!IG*' -F '!UISS*'"`
but still iOS class guard obfuscating it

```
2016-01-10 11:47:54.693 ios-class-guard[71726:1372666] Obfuscating@ class IGAxis 
2016-01-10 11:47:54.694 ios-class-guard[71726:1372666] Obfuscating @class IGCategoryAxisBase 
2016-01-10 11:47:54.694 ios-class-guard[71726:1372666] Obfuscating @class IGNumericAxisBase
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix is to remove the single quotes around the classes names
to be like this: `CLASS_GUARD_OPTS="-F !IG* -F !UISS* "`